# PayPal chained adaptative payments & CancelURL

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I'm using a wordpress with a shopping cart in a chained payment scenario that looks like this:

Buyer €€€ -> €€ Seller-> %fee -> € Me

I send:

```
actionType=PAY&
returnUrl=http://therabbitway.com/psicodigital/store/shopping-cart/confirmation/&
cancelUrl=http://therabbitway.com/psicodigital/store/shopping-cart/checkout/?cancel=1&
ipnNotificationUrl=http://therabbitway.com/psicodigital/store/payment-return/paypal-hained&
currencyCode=EUR&
feesPayer=PRIMARYRECEIVER&
trackingId=189224d4d766&
memo=PsicoDigital+Store+Purchase+-+Order+ID%3A+189224d4d766&
receiverList.receiver(0).email=seller_1311697317_biz%40gmail.com&
receiverList.receiver(0).amount=47&
receiverList.receiver(0).invoiceId=189224d4d766&
receiverList.receiver(0).paymentType=GOODS&
receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true&
receiverList.receiver(1).email=me_1311981478_biz%40gmail.com&
receiverList.receiver(1).amount=4.7&
receiverList.receiver(1).paymentType=SERVICE&
receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false
```

to https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay

Everything works great until I try to complete my purchase at PayPal's sandbox... an error message appears "Your payment can't be completed". 
When I click the "Return to store" button, PayPal calls the the link that I provided on the CancelUrl parameter...

The problem is: how do I show my client what when wrong on PayPal's side? How can I get some debug information to understand why is this happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Paypal send a lot of data (with post method) to the "return" URL (included in the form you show to the client) where you decide if the payment was successful. Make a dump of that data to see what you can use. But not complicate your life, Paypal already give us a good example about how verify payments in our site: [Instant Payment Notification - Code Samples](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/ipn-codesamples-pop-outside#php)

Comment: When PayPal redirects the use to CancelUrl the form is empty.